# WPF Combobox - Edited selected text

Tags: wpf, combobox

i have combobox with multiple lines in ComboboxItem. But i would like when i select item show only one line. Refer to the exhibit:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QuickSelectionDates}"    SelectedValuePath="Value" Width="110" Height="20"   VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
SelectedValue="{Binding Path=QuickSelectionDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="QuickSelectionDatesCombo"
                      Margin="5 0 0 0" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type library:ValueItem}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="11" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding AdditionalDesctiption}" FontSize="10"/> <!--DATE RANGE (second line)-->
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding QuickSelectionDateCommand}" 
                                               CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=QuickSelectionDatesCombo, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </ComboBox>
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you enough information to answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exists an event or property which has value which display first in combobox? I need after choosing value display only one row.
Thanks for answers